# copy constructor can't be called when call object o=13;

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
Object::Object(int x);
Object::~Object;
Object::Object(const &object);
```

when calling:

```
Object o=13;
```

I think it split 2 steps;

```
Object temp(13);
Object o=temp;
```

So it will call copy constructor,but I print the info:
there is no any copy constructor be called.

So can somebody help to explain it?
I think it should has no relations with NRVO or RVO.

Comment: possible because of the optimization of the compiler

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905869/isnt-return-value-optimization-rvo-a-bug

Answer (score 0):

There is elision of the copy constructor in your example.

From the c++ Standard:

> This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is
>   permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to
>   eliminate multiple copies):

...

> — when a temporary class object that
>   has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a
>   class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move
>   operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly
>   into the target of the omitted copy/move

Also there is an important note:

> [ Note: This two-stage overload resolution must be performed
>   regardless of whether copy elision will occur. It determines the
>   constructor to be called if elision is not performed, and the selected
>   constructor must be accessible even if the call is elided. —end note ]